# How to prevent Eclipse formatter from adding a whitespace after annotations in annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

When I format this code:

```
@JoinTable(name = "UTI_COLLECTER_CTN",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COD_UTI", referencedColumnName = "COD_UTI"),
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COD_CTN", referencedColumnName = "COD_CTN"))
```

eclipse adds a whitespace after each closing parenthesis of annotation in annotation, like this:

```
@JoinTable(name = "UTI_COLLECTER_CTN",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COD_UTI", referencedColumnName = "COD_UTI") ,
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COD_CTN", referencedColumnName = "COD_CTN") )
```

How to prevent it? (Removing all whitespaces in the formatter config does not change anything...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround, I add braces before and after the inner annotations:

```
@JoinTable(name = "UTI_COLLECTER_CTN",
  joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COD_UTI", referencedColumnName = "COD_UTI")},
  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COD_CTN", referencedColumnName = "COD_CTN")})
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

2) Click "Edit"

3) Open tab White Spaces

4) Expand "Declarations"

5) Click Annotations

6) Below you can find options for white spacing.

7) Remove thick of "before closing paranthesis"

I attached the picture for that. [image]

Comment: This checlbox is not checked in my config. I already tried to remove all checks in the White Spaces tab.

Comment: Maybe there is another Formatter is interfering your code ?